# What is com.apple.MobileSoftwareUpdate.UpdateBrainService doing?

Tags: services, auto-update

What is `com.apple.MobileSoftwareUpdate.UpdateBrainService`?

I have it running and using a lot of CPU resources. (about 300% CPU core in `top`)

I also found out it would mount a partition at `/System/Volumes/Update/mnt1` when it's running. I am not 100% sure if this mount point is related to this process. It's just my observation.

I am running MacOS Big Sur 11.2.3 (20D91).

My auto update is always turned **off**.

I found two online links talking about it, [link1](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/252177683) and [link2](https://www.reddit.com/r/MacOS/comments/lhhrb9/what_is/). But they don't explain what it is and why it's running.

Thank you very much.

**Update 1:**

I figured out even if I have `Automatically keep my Mac up to date` turned off. There is an `Advanced...` button in **Software Update** preference.

In the `Advanced...` setup popup window, it has the following options enabled: `Check for updates`, `Download new updates when available`.

I think this might cause `com.apple.MobileSoftwareUpdate.UpdateBrainService` process running and downloaded Big Sur updates. I am not very sure. Just a guess.

**Update 2:**

I have clicked **Restart** in ***Software Update*** preference.
Now, my system updated to 11.4.

I have turned off `Check for updates` in `Advanced...` window.

Hopefully, this issue and process will never run again.

Answer (score 2):

Found a great [detailed explainer](https://eclecticlight.co/2022/03/19/explainer-macos-updaters/) on the whole process at The Eclectic Light Company:

> ... the update takes three phases: download, preparation, and installation. The second of those, run by the Update Brain Service  com.apple.MobileSoftwareUpdate.UpdateBrainService, assembles all the components required, verifies them, decompresses data and readies it for the final phase.